# FACEBOOK GRAPH API - Find all comments a user has made

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I see the API has fields for getting comments given a post/photo/page id. Is there a field to grab a all comments made by a user?

something like this `/me?fields=comments`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, comments are always bound to another resource (post, photo, ...). There is no API to get ALL comments made by the user.